# Transfer function G(s)= 2/(0.0625*s^2+0.1*s+1) phase calculation problem for ω>ωn

Tags: transfer-function, bode-plot

I am trying to create a table of values and the bode plot for the tranfer function 
G(s)= 2/(0.0625*s^2 + 0.1*s + 1). However when i use values above ω{n} the the values of phase does not agree with the bode plot result of matlab or wolfram alpha. For example if ω=0.5, bode plot of wolfram gives arround Φ = -142deg but the calculation gives 41.633deg.
The phase equation is:
                     Φ(ω)= -arctan[0.1*ω/(1-ω^2/16)]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rHC7.png)
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdVhb.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a 4 quadrant arctan. In Excel, it is ATAN2(real, imag). For omega = 5, I get -138.37 deg.